# Como le puedo hacer para que primero me mande a la pagina y despues me muestre mi sweetalert del echo?

Tags: php, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
$NOMBRES = $_POST['NOMBRES'];
$PATERNO = $_POST['AP'];
$MATERNO = $_POST['AM'];
$CALLE = $_POST['CALLE'];
$EDIFICIO = $_POST['EDIFICIO'];
$NUMERO = $_POST['NUMERO'];
$FECHA_INGRESO = $_POST['FECHA_INGRESO'];
$HORA_INGRESO = $_POST['HORA_INGRESO'];
$FECHA_SALIDA = $_POST['FECHA_SALIDA'];
$HORA_SALIDA = $_POST['HORA_SALIDA'];

$COMPLETO = $NOMBRES . " " . $PATERNO . " " . $MATERNO;

include '../ConexionABaseCondominio.php';
include '../scripts.php';
$consulta = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $database.control_acceso (ID_ACCESO, NOMBRES, PATERNO, MATERNO, COMPLETO, CALLE, EDIFICIO, NUMERO, FECHA_INGRESO, HORA_INGRESO, FECHA_SALIDA, HORA_SALIDA)
        VALUES (null, '$NOMBRES', '$PATERNO', '$MATERNO', '$COMPLETO','$CALLE', '$EDIFICIO', '$NUMERO','$FECHA_INGRESO','$HORA_INGRESO','$FECHA_SALIDA','$HORA_SALIDA')");

echo '<script>
const Toast = Swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: "top-start",
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 2000,
    timerProgressBar: true,
    didOpen: (toast) => {
        toast.addEventListener("mouseenter", Swal.stopTimer)
        toast.addEventListener("mouseleave", Swal.resumeTimer)
    }
})

Toast.fire({
    icon: "success",
    title: "¡Registro exitoso!"
})
</script>';
```

Pero mi pregunta aqui es que como le puedo hacer para que primero me envie a la pagina ../xC_acceso y despues me muestre mi echo que tiene el codigo?
Lo he intentando con Location, pero solamente me manda a la pagina y no me muestra el alert...

Comment: ¿Entiendes que PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta en el servidor? ¿Entiendes que una vez que la página ha sido enviada al cliente, no hay nada que puedas hacer con PHP para realizar manipulaciones de DOM? ¿Entiendes que Javascript es lo que debes usar para trabajar con Sweet Alert y por lo tanto es tarea del navegador una vez que la página ha sido totalmente cargada en el cliente? La comunicación entre cliente y servidor (Javascript y PHP en este caso) debes hacerla con llamadas Ajax. Saludos

Comment: Entonces como le hago? -Saludos